# Calculating fundamental group of Klein bottle

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups, klein-bottle

To calculate the fundamental group of the Klein bottle, $X$, we can find path connected open sets, $U$, $V$,and $U \cap V$, satisfying $U\cup V= X$.
I know we can choose $U$ and $V$ as follows:[![$U$ with a fixed point $p$][1]][1][![$V$ with a fixed point $p$][2]][2]
then $U\cap V$ is just [![$U\cap V$ with a fixed point $p$][3]][3]
$U$ is homotopic equivalent to $S^1\vee S^1$ up to homeomorphism and $V$ is contractible. $U\cap V$ has a strong deformation retract to $S^1$.
Then $\pi_1(U,p) \cong\pi_1(S^1, *)\cong \langle a,b \rangle$, $\pi_1(V,p)\cong  \{1\}$ and $\pi_1(U\cap V, p)\cong \pi_1(S^1, *)\cong \langle x \rangle$.

By Seifert-Van-Kampen, $$\pi_1(X, p)\cong (\pi_1(U,p)*\pi_1(V,p))/N$$
where $$N=\langle \langle \iota_0(y) (\iota_1(y))^{-1}: y\in \pi_1(U\cap V,p) \rangle \rangle$$
the normal closure generated by elements in $\{ \iota_0(y) (\iota_1(y))^{-1}: y\in \pi_1(U\cap V, p) \}$
$\iota_0$ and $\iota_1$ are two maps as follows:
\begin{array}
& & \pi_1(U, p)& \\
& \nearrow{\iota_0} & & \\
\pi_1(U\cap V, p)& & &  \\
& \searrow{\iota_1} & & \\
& \pi_1( V, p) & &
\end{array}
Intuitively, $abab^{-1}$ is a loop in $U$, but what does this mean, I need to make this   expression more precise. And in some notes, some people say: in $\iota_0: \pi_1(U\cap V,p) \rightarrow \pi_1(U,p)\cong\langle a,b \rangle$, $x$ should be mapped to $abab^{-1}$. Why? Why not map $x$ to some generator of $\pi_1(U,p)$, say $a$ or $b$?
Some people say that I need to see what paths the circle $S^1$ traverses when it gets projected to the skeleton of that Klein bottle. Why? Is this idea precise? Can anybody elaborate on this?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSp1T.jpg
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDSLg.jpg
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQC4r.jpg

Comment: It might help clarify things to abstract a bit. Prove as an exercise in Siefert-Van Kampen that if $X$ is a cell complex with one vertex, then its fundamental group is the quotient of the free group on the edges by the relations that come from the attaching maps of the two-faces.

Comment: What do you mean by "why not map"? You have a concrete function and it works the way it works.